# Where can I get vector datasets for Nasarawa state in Nigeria?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, africa

I would be happy to be pointed to the right direction where I can access vector data for Nasarawa state in Nigeria?

Comment: I take it the data from openstreetmap.org is insufficient?

Comment: The Nasarawa Geographic Information Service (NAGIS) is pretty sparse - sad : http://www.nagis.org/

Comment: Is it missing from the answer here? http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/114671

Answer (score 3):

You can get some spatial data by selcting your country name. http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata?